# Can ANOVA and t-test give different results?

Tags: anova, t-test

Specifically, two group ANOVA vs unpaired t-test. My understanding was that those would always give the same p-value, but someone just told me that there could be rare cases where the ANOVA and the t-test would lead to different p-values. My questions: (a) is this true? and if yes, (b) under what conditions would this be more likely to occur? Thanks.

Comment: Which t-test, exactly?  There are several variants.  Many people would automatically use a version that accommodates the possibility of unequal variances in the groups.  That is likely to yield a p-value different from ANOVA, which assumes equal variances.

Comment: If you compare equal variance t with equal variance anova on 2 groups they should give the same p-values; indeed, $t^2=F$. However if one uses say a Welch-Satterthwaite approach for dealing with unequal variance and the other does not (and either might) then they can differ. For the equal-variance case, I give an outline of the connection in my answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141578/effect-of-sample-size-in-f-test/141580#141580) (in the latter part) both doing some of the algebra and showing a specific numerical example (it doesn't do a complete derivation, however).

Answer (score 1):

The two should give the same results in all  cases.  ANOVA is a generalization of t-test.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. Do you know of a link to a (ideally simple) mathematical proof of this on line?

Comment: Not offhand.  Probably the thing to do is to examine the formulas for ANOVA and the t test and see the similarities.  Others here would be better guides.

Comment: ANOVA uses the F distribution, a t test uses the t distribution. The F is a squared t, therefore they will always give the answer to the same question.

Comment: As others have noted, if the pooled sum of squares is used for the denominator of the t then the F is the square of the corresponding t and the p-values are identical. Other forms of the t will differ from the usual F.