# Fitting Mixture of Poissons Without GLM

Tags: r, mixture-distribution

I am looking for a way to fit a mixture of 2 univariate Poisson distributions, but the R packages I checked, `mixtools` and `flexmix`, assume a GLM model. They require a "formula", etc.. How can I fit a non-GLM model to my data?

In *Hidden Markov Models for Time Series: An Introduction Using R* by MacDonald et al. one exercise suggests to fit Poisson distributions using `nlm` of `optim`; I guess that is possible too, the error function could be tied to the likelihood of the data, the routine would optimize on that.

Note: Per @Tim's comment, I used

```
library("flexmix")
y <- c(4,5,4,1,0,4,3,4,0,6,3,3,4,0,2,6,3,3,5,4,5,3,
       1,4,4,1,5,5,3,4,2,5,2,2,3,4,2,1,3,2,2,1,1,1,
       1,3,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,3,1,0,3,2,2,0,1,1,1,0,1,
       0,1,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,2,3,3,1,1,2,1,1,1,
       1,2,4,2,0,0,0,1,4,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1)
df <- data.frame(y)
res <- flexmix(y ~ 1, data = df, k = 2, model = FLXMRglm(family = "poisson"))
print (summary(res))
print (posterior(res))
```

This seemed to work; my goal was fitting two Poisson distributions to coal mining accident data to find a switch point between two different regimes.

Thanks,

Comment: What is the problem with GLM and formula for you? You can always use `variable ~ 1` formula for intercept-only (i.e. mean only) model...

Comment: It's not a problem per se - I dont need it. I took your advice, and it seemed to work. I will update the question.

Comment: Glad it helped, I posted a more detailed answer with some references FYI.

Comment: Another quick question: the model above returns me 1.0101464 and -0.580075 - my per-cluster Poisson lambda's? One value is negative though, aren't Poisson lambdas supposed to be all positive?

Comment: Well... Poisson's $\lambda$ are only non-negative integers, but you are using GLM with Poisson link function - that is not the same. Take a look at literature related to GLM and multiple threads here on GLM and link functions like http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20523/difference-between-logit-and-probit-models#30909 to understent them better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any GLM model (see [more about GLM in here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59047/how-are-regression-the-t-test-and-the-anova-all-versions-of-the-general-linear)) in univariate case, if the general case is

$$ Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \varepsilon $$

then you can use intercept-only model

$$ Y = \beta_0 + \varepsilon $$

(or in R formula `Y ~ 1`). Such model simply estimates the mean, e.g.

```
> mean(mtcars$mpg)
[1] 20.09062
> lm(mpg ~ 1, mtcars)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ 1, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  
      20.09
```

This can be extended into other cases, like in the one you described. In fact, if you look deeper into [flexmix](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexmix/index.html) documentation (see also both JSS papers [here](http://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v011i08/) and [here](http://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v028i04) and multiple papers by [Bettina Grün](http://ifas.jku.at/gruen/publications.html) and [Friedrich Leisch](https://homepage.boku.ac.at/leisch/papers/fl-publications.html) that are available online), you'll see that multiple examples deal with such intercept-only formulas where the `FLX...` part is used for more advanced features of the model.

Answer (score 0):

Two code examples I found, one based on R nlm, the other Matlab's mle.

R

```
xf <- c(4,5,4,1,0,4,3,4,0,6,3,3,4,0,2,6,3,3,5,4,5,3,1,4,4,1,5,5,3,4,2,5,2,2,3,4,2,1,3,2,2,1,1,1,1,3,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,3,1,0,3,2,2,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,2,3,3,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,4,2,0,0,0,1,4,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1)

udist <- function(n) rep(1/n, n) 

#natural to working
n2wp <- function(p) {
    m <- length(p)
    log(p[2:m]/(1 - sum(p[2:m])))
}

#working to natural
w2np <- function(lp) {
    rv <- exp(lp)/(1 + sum(exp(lp)))    
    c(1 - sum(rv), rv)
}

#optimisation function
of <- function(pv, m, x) {
    #convert working parameters to natural paramters
    pr <- exp(pv[1:m])
    probs <- w2np(pv[(m+1):(2*m - 1)])
    #calculate -ve log likelihood
    -sum(log(outer(x, pr, dpois) %*% probs))
}

#initial estimates and probabilities for 2, 3 and 4 distributions
#the lambda values I just guess, and use an uniform distribution
#for the initial mixing distribution.
pv <- c(log(c(1, 2)), n2wp(udist(2)))

#number of distributions to fit
m <- 2

#fit using nlm
fv <-nlm(of, pv, m, xf, print.level=0) 
rv <- fv$est

#lambda estimates
exp(rv[1:m])
#mixing distribution
w2np(rv[(m+1):(2*m-1)])
```

Matlab

```
x = [poissrnd(1,100,1); poissrnd(10,200,1)];
f = @(x,p,logmu1,logmu2) p*poisspdf(x,exp(logmu1)) + (1-p)*poisspdf(x,exp(logmu2));
mle(x,'pdf',f,'start',[.5 2 4])
exp(ans(2:3))
```