# MIXED MODEL - can a fixed factor be continuous?

Tags: mixed-model, spss, fixed-effects-model, marginal-model

I am using the linear mixed function in SPSS and want to determine whether a continuous variable (`attendance`) has an effect on the repeated measurement of my DV (`GLS`). My hypothesis is that `attendance` does have an effect on the DV. It was suggested that I add `attendance` as a covariate but also as a fixed effect. From what I've read it seems like fixed effects are always categorical so does this make sense?

```
MIXED GLS BY TIME WITH ATTENDANCE

/FIXED=TIME ATTENDANCE |SSTYPE(3)

/METHOD=REML

/REPEATED=TIME | SUBJECT(PARTICIPANT_ID) COVTYPE(UN).

OR, should attendance only be a covariate? 

MIXED GLS BY TIME WITH ATTENDANCE

/FIXED=TIME ATTENDANCE |SSTYPE(3)

/METHOD=REML

/REPEATED=TIME | SUBJECT(PARTICIPANT_ID) COVTYPE(UN).
```

Comment: There is an underlying statistical question here but nevertheless this looks like a question on SPSS syntax to do something. If so, it is off-topic here. Please see advice on software-specific questions in the Help Center.

Comment: @NickCox  I agree, but I think the question could be edited to emphasize the statistical point.  The main question seems to be statistics, not syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Standard regression model includes *slope* and *intercept*, [regression is related to ANOVA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59047/how-are-regression-the-t-test-and-the-anova-all-versions-of-the-general-linear) with [dummy-coded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_%28statistics%29) group memberships. Mixed effects model can include, besides the fixed effects as in regression, also random effects: *random slopes* and *random intercepts* (cf. Gelman & Hill, 2006). Grouping variable cannot be continuous, so such case is impossible, however you can have fixed effects for dummy-coded groups - the same as in linear regression.

---

Gelman, A. & Hill, J. (2006). [Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/). Cambridge.